# How do you get the past live streams with YouTube data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API has:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.liveBroadcastContent

but this shows whether you are already live streaming or there is a scheduled live stream.

And the YouTube livestream API doesn't seem to deal with non-LIVE entries:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Use

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails

works with api_key unlike the `fileDetails` in the old answer.

---

**OLD:**

I was lucky and spotted that the past live streams are saved with file name `livestream.str`.

So, using the YouTube Data API to get videos with filename `livestream.str` should work.

To get this filename, you need the OAuth2 authorization. If you use the API key you will get `403 error`. Then use the `part=fileDetails`:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters